# Mergeable selector SCSS-lint

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors, scss-lint

I'm a beginner in **CSS** and I'm working on a project that has **scss-lint** to validate stylesheets formats.

I have the following classes:

```
.arrow--right {
  border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
  border-left: 12px solid $border-color;
  border-top: 12px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform .1s linear;
  width: 0;
}

.arrow--right.hover {
  border-left-color: $brand-highlight;
}
```

The idea is that whenever I hover other element, `hover` class is added to the arrow thus coloring it.

> SCSS-Lint error: MergeableSelector: Merge rule `.arrow--right.hover` with `.arrow--right`

How can I merge these two rules without affecting the behaviour I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lint warning means that you should join the `.hover` amendment within the main class selector using the `&` operator, like this:

```
.arrow--right {
  border-bottom: 12px solid transparent;
  border-left: 12px solid $border-color;
  border-top: 12px solid transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: transform .1s linear;
  width: 0;

  &.hover {
    border-left-color: $brand-highlight;
  }
}
```